# Acessar métodos através de um componente pai em um filho com Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

Olá, estou tendo muita dificuldades para conseguir passar uma informação entre 2 componentes trabalhando com Angular 1. Este é meu exemplo:

```
angular.module("parent",["child"]).component("parent",{
  template : "<p> <child name></child> </div>",
  controllerAs:"parent",
  controller : {
    constructor(){}
  }
});

angular.module("child",[]).component("child",{
  binding : {
    "name" = "="
  }
  template : "<span>{{name}}</span>",
  controllerAs : "child",
  controller : {
    constructor(){
      this.name = name;
    }
  }
});
```

Até agora, caso eu informe o valor manualmente em `<child name="foo"></child>` o componente **child** tem seu conteúdo alterado. O problema é que não estou entendendo como que através do **parent** eu vou conseguir alterar o conteúdo do parâmetro name do componente **child**

Alguém poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é simplesmente passar uma propriedade do componente pai ao atributo `name`. Logo, ao mudar o valor dessa propriedade no componente pai, o processo de *binding* do AngularJs se encarregará de propagar a mudança para o componente filho.

> Você está utilizando o modificador de *binding* `=`, isso quer dizer que a propriedade `name` pode ser modificada tanto no componente pai quanto no filho.

Exemplo:

```js
angular.module('parent', ['child']).component('parent', {
  template: 'parent: {{ parent.myName }} <br> child: <child name="parent.myName"></child>',
  controllerAs: 'parent',
  controller: function() {
    this.myName = 'foo';
  }
});

angular.module('child', []).component('child', {
  bindings: {
    name: '<'
  },
  template: '<span>{{ child.name }}</span>',
  controllerAs: 'child',
  controller: function() {
    this.name = 'bar';
  }
});

angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['parent']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<parent></parent>
```

Comment: nesse caso, se eu passar o binding como `"<"` eu vou conseguir alterar somente o que foi do parent para o child? eu cheguei em uma solução parecida mas, ao alterar o child, o parent também mudava...

Comment: @LeandroLUK Sim, é assim que você distingue um componente *dumb* de um componente *smart*, se você utilizar o `<`, qualquer mudança que precisar ser feita, terá de ser delegada ao componente pai.

Comment: mas então como posso ter uma via de tráfego somente do parent para o child? não posso alterar o parent pois ele é um MutateObserver direto no mongodb, ou seja, ele irá alterar quando entender que há a mudança feita pelo child no banco

Comment: @LeandroLUK  Exatamente utilizando o `<`, onde a possessão vem do componente pai. Mas se você quer atualizar os dados do pai vindos do filho, o ideal é criar o bind de um método para que o filho emita a mudança para o pai ao invés de mudar o model do pai.

Comment: minha situação é, tenho uma list de usuários, que abre uma div com os details de um usuário. no meu código hoje, quando mudo o details, ele está mudando a list, e não deve ser feito isso porque no exato momento que o banco muda, meu código ja atualiza "reativamente"

Comment: @LeandroLUK É que provavelmente os dois são o mesmo model. Usando o `<` no binding não previne isso?

Comment: @LeandroLUK eu atualizei a resposta com um código funcionando. Também, tinha um erro de digitação no parâmetro `bindings` que estava só `binding`.